# Python - List comprehension how to insert 2 elements at a time?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a `pluralize` function in python which prints the plural form of a word

```
pluralize("wolf") = wolves
```

for example, in my input_list

```
input_list = ["wolf","dog","cat","cow","pig"]
```

I can do this simple list comprehension to get the plural forms populated

```
output_list = [pluralize(data) for data in input_list]
```

giving `["wolves","dogs","cats.....]`

However I need

```
["wolves","wolf","dogs","dog","cats","cat","cows","cow"....]
```

How can I get this list generated by comprehension?

I mean something like

```
output_list = [pluralize(data),data for data in input_list]
```

(obviously doesn't work)

Comment: You mean `pluralize(data), data`; your plural forms come first..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, edited, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add another loop:

```
[word for data in input_list for word in (pluralize(data), data)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> plural_forms = {'wolf': 'wolves', 'dog': 'dogs', 'cat': 'cats', 'cow': 'cows', 'pig': 'pigs'}
>>> pluralize = plural_forms.get
>>> input_list = ["wolf","dog","cat","cow","pig"]
>>> [word for data in input_list for word in (pluralize(data), data)]
['wolves', 'wolf', 'dogs', 'dog', 'cats', 'cat', 'cows', 'cow', 'pigs', 'pig']
```

Answer (score 9):

```
sum([[x, plural(x)] for x in data], [])
```

likewise:

```
>>> sum([[x, x.upper()] for x in "hello"], [])
['h', 'H', 'e', 'E', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'o', 'O']
```

Comment: This works, but how does `sum()` flatten the list of lists?

Comment: It works because `+` is a concatenation operator for lists in python. `[1] + [2] == [1, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this Helps,

```
output_list = [item for sublist in [[pluralize(data),data] for data in input_list]for item in sublist]
```

Best,